# What is the DocuSign rest api endpoint that mimics Share to Folder action for templates?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create templates via DocuSign API and as part of the solution design, the templates my app will create needs to be shared with Folder so that whoever has access the folder, will be able to see the templates generated by the app.

This functionality exists in the UI. However, I wasn't able to figure out what rest API I can use to mimic the same behavior of Share to Folder button in Templates UI. I looked the rest API documentation of DocuSign but still unable to figure out how to do that.

Is anyone able to help here?

I tried Folder Api to move the item from my templates to the Shared Template folder. However, this works a bit weird. When I move items from My Templates to Shared Folder, using the `PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}` endpoint described [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes)

Using `PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}` endpoint did not work as expected. As soon as I move envelopes to a shared template folder, templates are *not* appearing under My Templates folder anymore. However, when using Share to Folder feature in the UI, template still remains in the My Templates folder and appears in Shared template folder. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share a template using the template share API

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/updateGroupShare

```
PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/{templatePart}
```

At this time, you can only share with a group, which is what templatePart is.

Comment: Group is group of users right?  Are you saying share to folder is not possible at the moment via Public Api ?

Comment: you are correct. the API to move to a folder is not currently public, I am not sure if/when it will be public, I'll try to check for you and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks will try to find alternative solution approach then.

Comment: just did. Thanks.